# Python: what's a more compact/efficient way to strip string of a suffix from list?

Tags: python, string, strip

Is there a more compact and efficient way of stripping a string of any suffix from a given list, i.e.:

```
sfxs = ['suffix1', 'sfx2', 'suffix333']
s = 'string-to-process-sfx2'
for sfx in sfxs:
    i = s.find(sfx)
    if not i == -1:
        s = s[:i]
        break
```

Suffixes are of different lengths

Comment: what about `s.endswith(suffix)`?

Comment: ...which is more efficient because it only needs to look at the end of the string, rather than searching all through it as `find` does. Also, this prevents issues where the `sfx` is somewhere *other* than the end of the string.

Comment: `re.sub(suffix+'$', '', string-to-process)`?

Comment: What if the string has more than one of the suffixes at the end? Do you want to turn `string-to-process-suffix1sfx2` into `string-to-process-`? What about `string-to-process-sfx2suffix1`?  If you need to handle both of those, then a loop like this can't work; do you see why?

Comment: Doesn't `endswith` return `True/False` rather than a position? Then I would need to compute that position anyway

Comment: @Karl Good point. I forgot to mention that in my case it's either one of the suffixes or none at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `re.sub`.

```
>>> import re
>>> sfxs = ['suffix1', 'sfx2', 'suffix333']
>>> s = 'string-to-process-sfx2'
>>> re.sub(r'(' + '|'.join(sfxs) + r')$', '',s)
'string-to-process-'
>>> re.sub(r'\b(' + '|'.join(sfxs) + r')$', '',s)
'string-to-process-'

>>> re.sub(r'-(' + '|'.join(sfxs) + r')$', '',s)
'string-to-process'
```

`'|'.join(sfxs)` helps to join the `suffix` list with `|` as delimiter. So `r'(' + '|'.join(sfxs) + r')$'` would form a regex like `(suff1|suff2|suff3|..)$`. Note that `$` anchor, which matches the end of the line. So this would do matching only at the end.

```
>>> re.sub(r'(' + '|'.join(sorted(sfxs, key=lambda x:len(x), reverse=True)) + r')$', '',s)
'string-to-process-'
```

Comment: assuming there actually is a word boundary preceding it (I couldnt necessarilly tell)

Comment: like it better than my version! +1

Comment: meh no its not disregard (I apparently dont understand regex as well as I thought... you are right it does not appear to need to be sorted)

Comment: I couldnt break it when I actually went into python even without the sort ... :P but I still think its should be sorted :P (but yes excellent answer) `sorted(sfxs,key=len)[::-1]` is a little shorter though :P

Answer (score 1):

```
sfxs = ['suffix1', 'sfx2', 'suffix333']
s = 'string-to-process-sfx2'
for sfx in sfxs:
    if s.endswith(sfx):
        s = s[:-len(sfx)]
        break
print(s)
```

is slightly more efficient because the string comparison looks at the end of the string only.

Comment: totally OT ... but excellent name:) that is my favorite book :)

Comment: i'll say hi to YT from you.

Answer (score 0):

```
sfxs = ['suffix1', 'sfx2', 'suffix333']
s = 'string-to-process-sfx2'
for sfx in sfxs:
    if sfx in s:
        s.replace(sfx, "")
```

Should do it.  Check to ensure the suffix is in the string, then remove it if it is.

Comment: Note that this will remove `sfx` *elsewhere in `s`*; to only remove it from the end, you could do e.g. `s = s[:-len(sfx)]`.

Comment: Good point, also note @hiroprotagonist addresses this by using `endswith()` rather than `in`